# It is possible to use a list within a While-loop?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to use the form

```
b = {...}, While[test[b], body]
```

but do not get any results. My code is:

```
b = {1, 1, 1}; While[b < {4, 4, 4}, Print[b]; b++]
```

It is the right way to proceed?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? `List`s cannot be compared that way, but you could for example compare their first elements, given that in your code all elements of `b` are always the same. For example with something like `b = {1, 1, 1}; While[First[b] < 4, Print[b]; b++]`

Comment: Your test within the `While` must evaluate to `True` for the loop to proceed. `{1,1,1} < {4,4,4}` doesn't return `True`, it doesn't run, why should it, what should the results be? Perhaps you want to test `And @@ Thread[b < {4, 4, 4}]`

Comment: You are performing operations on lists like they are variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trying to guess at what may be confusing to a beginner about Mathematica, the following may be helpful:

In many other languages if you call a function it either stops with an error or returns with a result.  Due to the symbolic nature of Mathematica, some things simply do not evaluate instead of showing an error.

```
1 < 2
(* True *)

2 < 1
(* False *)

x < 2
(* x < 2 *)
```

The last one is in fact just a symbolic way to represent an inequality (it is not an error!)

`While` expects its first argument to evaluate either to `True` or `False`.  It treats everything else as `False`.

Some languages allow array comparisons.  Mathematica doesn't.  `{1,1,1} < {4,4,4}` will not evaluate, as you can (and should) test.

To do element-wise comparison, use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html).

```
Thread[{1, 2, 3} < {2, 2, 2}]
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

Use [`And`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to test that element of a boolean list are `True`:

```
And @@ Thread[{1, 2, 3} < {2, 2, 2}]
```

As you can see, *Mathematica is different*.  It is a good idea to go through a proper tutorial when you start out:

- https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are trying to pick the elements < 4 from a list, here are several ways to do it.

#### Procedural

```
Module[{r = {}, i = 0, n = Length[b]},
  While[i < n, If[b[[++i]] < 4, AppendTo[r, b[[i]]]]];
  r]
```

This is the most bug-prone and inefficient of all the methods presented in this answer.

#### Quasi-procedural

```
Table[If[b[[i]] < 4, b[[i]], Nothing], {i, Length[b]}]
```

#### Functional

```
If[# < 4, #, Nothing] & /@ b
```

or

```
Pick[b, Thread[b < 4]]
```

This last one is probably best, since `Pick` is optimized for this kind of problem.

---

With

```
SeedRandom[2]; b = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 10]
```

> `{6, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 2, 6, 6, 1}`

all of the above methods give the result

> `{2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1}`